# How can I get rid of the "about:blank" label in a popup window in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I construct a string containing html and pop it up with:

```
var tbox=window.open("","","height=450,width=500");
```

The html contains a title block.

```
 <title>Strangle</title>
```

I get a popup box labelled "Strangle - Google Chrome", and INSIDE that box is another box labeled "about:blank", and inside that box is the html page I constructed.

Is there no way to get rid of that intrusive "about:blank"?

If I wanted to pass a url named, say, Strangle.com, I assume I'd have to run  a server on my machine. That seems like a terrible kludge just to get rid of an annoying bit of cruft.

Comment: `INSIDE that box is another box labeled "about:blank"` Do you mean the address bar? If so, you can hide it

Answer (score 0):

```
var tbox=window.open(null,"","height=450,width=500");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your answer to explain *why* this would solve the problem at hand. Note that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to future readers. Thus please, add some text and/or comments explaining why this works.

Comment: Alas, when I used 'null' as you suggested, I got an error "Unable to find your window".

Comment: Actually this first part is for url so you should define some url in your code and them pass that into the param or either hide it with the css.